# Routing from 2 WAN to same LAN

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, routing

I'm using a Linux based router appliance (named Zeroshell), but it should be a question related to generic Linux routing.

The router computer has 4 NICs, named ETH0 to ETH3.

- ETH0 is on the actual LAN (subnet 192.168.241.0/24) IP 192.168.241.254
- ETH1 is on a WAN connection router (subnet 192.168.1.0/24) IP 192.168.1.1, GW 192.168.1.254
- ETH2 is on a another WAN connection router (subnet 192.168.2.0/24) IP 192.168.2.1, GW 192.168.2.254
- ETH3 is on another LAN dedicated for guests (subnet 192.168.230.0/24) IP 192.168.230.254

The default gateway on the router is set to 192.168.2.254 so all outgoing traffic uses the second WAN connection (optic fiber), and NAT is enabled on both ETH1 and ETH2.

On first WAN router, 192.168.1.1 is set as the DMZ.
On second WAN router, 192.168.2.1 is set as the DMZ.

I've set some port forwarding on port 80 on both ETH1 and ETH2 to a computer lying in the ETH0 subnet.

When connecting to the second WAN's public IP with a browser, I get the website hosted on the internal computer.

When connecting to the first WAN's public IP with a browser, connection stays stuck.

I'm pretty sure this has to deal with the default gateway set to the second WAN's router making all traffic go to him, even if it originated from the first WAN router.

So my question is : HOW should I configure the routing tables on my router so that it can handle incoming connections from both WANs, forward them to the relevant LAN computer and route answers to the proper WAN ?

---

EDIT:

**Adding routing tables from the Webserver :**

```
root@webserver:/# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:f1:03:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.241.23/24 brd 192.168.241.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@webserver:/# ip route show
default via 192.168.241.254 dev eth0
10.8.0.0/24 via 192.168.241.21 dev eth0
192.168.240.0/24 via 192.168.241.21 dev eth0
192.168.241.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.241.23
```

**Adding routing tables from the Router :**

```
root@rtr ~> ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,10000> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
3: ETH00: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,10000> mtu 1500 qdisc mq qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:f1:05:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.230.254/24 brd 192.168.230.255 scope global ETH00:00
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fef1:508/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: ETH01: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,10000> mtu 1500 qdisc mq qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:f1:05:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.1/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global ETH01:00
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a01:e35:2e74:9560:215:5dff:fef1:509/64 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft 86156sec preferred_lft 86156sec
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fef1:509/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: ETH02: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,10000> mtu 1500 qdisc mq qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:f1:05:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global ETH02:00
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fef1:50b/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: ETH03: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,10000> mtu 1500 qdisc mq qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:f1:05:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.241.254/24 brd 192.168.241.255 scope global ETH03:00
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fef1:50c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue
    link/ether 9e:3d:6a:0e:65:39 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.141.142/24 brd 192.168.141.255 scope global dummy0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: dummy1: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,10000> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue
    link/ether ee:6e:6f:33:32:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.142.142/32 brd 192.168.142.255 scope global dummy1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ec6e:6fff:fe33:3234/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: DEFAULTBR: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop
    link/ether 0a:61:ef:f2:09:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: VPN99: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 10                                                                                                                                     0
    link/ether 1a:e8:0e:ee:78:aa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.250.254/24 brd 192.168.250.255 scope global VPN99:00
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop
    link/ether 8e:65:6c:3d:76:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
12: bond1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop
    link/ether 1e:34:34:54:8d:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
13: bond2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop
    link/ether 5a:bc:4c:86:83:dc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
14: bond3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop
    link/ether 6e:81:53:3e:0a:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
15: bond4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop
    link/ether 6a:35:c8:45:d1:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
16: bond5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop
    link/ether ca:5d:10:21:02:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
17: bond6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop
    link/ether 82:60:85:97:d4:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
18: bond7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop
    link/ether b6:fc:c9:a5:06:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
19: bond8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop
    link/ether ce:75:5d:e5:7d:69 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
20: bond9: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop
    link/ether 2e:ef:1e:89:26:1b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
root@rtr ~> ip route show
default via 192.168.1.254 dev ETH02
192.168.1.0/24 dev ETH02  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1
192.168.2.0/24 dev ETH01  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.1
192.168.230.0/24 dev ETH00  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.230.254
192.168.240.0/24 via 192.168.241.21 dev ETH03
192.168.241.0/24 dev ETH03  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.241.254
192.168.250.0/24 dev VPN99  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.250.254
```

Comment: Please show us the routing tables of both router and web server. Use the command `ip addr show; ip route show` on both servers

Comment: Is the router set up to NAT between the LAN and WANs?

Comment: Added the requested routing tables and yes, NAT is enabled and working fine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with such a dual-homed setup is that the return packets originating from the webserver on the ETH0 network follow the default gateway, which is only correct for connections coming in through that interface. I've run into this myself.

The solution I use is to add an extra IP address to the webserver on the ETH0 network (I'm assuming 192.168.241.24), and use that as the DNAT target for connections coming in through the second WAN interface. Then add a routing rule that the second IP address gets routed out through the second WAN interface.

You need to understand a little bit about Linux policy based routing. Do `ip rule show`:

```
0:  from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

When you do `ip route show` you show the "main" table as default. You can show one of the other tables by adding `table $name`, e.g.:

```
$ ip route show table local
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 192.168.0.0 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.27
local 192.168.1.27 dev eth0 proto kernel scope host src 192.168.1.27
broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.27
```

You can add your own tables; edit `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` and add two lines:

```
11 WAN1
12 WAN2
```

Now you can add the default routes over ETH01 and ETH02 to the respective tables:

```
# ip route add default via 192.168.2.254 table WAN1
# ip route add default via 192.168.1.254 table WAN2
```

(You first describe ETH01 as having 192.168.1.254 as gateway and ETH02 and having 192.168.2.254 but then your `ip route show` output disagrees, so I'm going with the latter... aside from the ETH1 / ETH01 difference.)

Now you need to add a rule to use the WAN1 table for traffic coming in from the second webserver IP address:

```
# ip rule add from 192.168.241.24 lookup WAN1 prio 1000
```

Now, when traffic comes in from ETH01 and gets sent via DNAT to the second IP address of the webserver, the webserver will return packets from that address and the rule will match that address and send return traffic via ETH01.

You don't really need the WAN2 table in this scenario, however if the router system itself needs to be accessible from both WAN interfaces, or if you want to be able to choose what WAN interface for whatever then it's useful to have it.

Comment: The issue technically isn't that they go out via the default gateway, but that NAT changes their source IP to that of the default gateway's interface. This is different from the destination IP that the connection was originally established on, and thus is not recognised as the same connection by the remote computer.

Comment: @CyberJacob there's an RFC (I can't find which right now) that says that an internet connection provider should not accept packets from their clients with source addresses that do not originate from within their address space, to combat spoofing of such addresses, so even if the NAT would set the source IP to the correct one, if the packet goes out through the wrong interface, it probably won't arrive at the destination anyway.