# Understanding Netplan / NIC

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, router, loopback

I have a set of 5 static ip addresses.  Currently I only have 1 server, so I want to route 2 static IP's to the same server.  At the same time I still want the server to be part of the local network.

I have a nic with interfaces eno1, eno2, eno3, eno4.  eno1 is connected to my router, which leases using dhcp.

I've set eno2 and eno4 up like this:

```
network:
   version: 2
   renderer: networkd
   ethernets:
      eno2:
         dhcp4: no
         addresses: [83.111.42.21/29]
         gateway4: 83.111.42.26
         nameservers:
            addresses: [75.75.75.75,75.75.76.76]
      eno4:
         dhcp4: no
         addresses: [83.111.42.22/29]
         gateway4: 83.111.42.26
         nameservers:
            addresses: [75.75.75.75,75.75.76.76]
```

I thought, because these were static IP's directly linked to the server, that locally I would be able to access them using the actual static IP, but I'm unable.  Do statically assigned IP's also suffer from loopback?

I did notice that if I disable eno1 (no connection to lan) that I am able to directly connect to the IP's.  As soon as I re-enable eno1, I am once more no longer able.

I could really use help understanding the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple interfaces that are all members of the same subnet, then you will see via '`ip route`' command that the server has multiple routes it can follow, to get to the same subnet. See [Dual Network Gateway on CentOS 6.7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491907/dual-network-gateway-on-centos-6-7) and [Routing from 2 WAN to same LAN](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419047/routing-from-2-wan-to-same-lan/419117#419117)... even though they describe ifupdown interfaces, the theory applies to netplan. The default gateway will route out all non-LAN traffic fine, but you will lose packets (spoofing security) if they arrive at another 'local' interface but are then routed back out the gateway interface (for example).

To support multiple local interfaces properly, the purist approach would say you should create separate routing tables for each interface. But if you want, just try removing the gateway route (which is effectively what happens when you remove eno1), leaving the local interfaces only, and you should be fine. Of course, you will have to add explicit routes for the gateway traffic, which is another topic.